# In the QBundle Burstcoin Wallet, why is a fee of 1 BURST required to set the account info?

Tags: wallet

The QBundle Burstcoin Wallet (v2.0.4, installed to Windows 10) requires a fee of 1 BURST to set the Name, Description, and Passphrase for the wallet.

Admittedly, the fee is very low (worth about 2.5 cents at the moment), but why is a fee required? Who receives it?

Comment: Are you referring to the online wallet or, the packaged windows launcher version?

Comment: @Willtech The Windows version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are claiming an address on the blockchain. The fee makes sure no one will (try to) claim all addresses on the network.

Comment: Does the fee just go to the miners?

Comment: sorry for the delay but yes. the fee goes to the miner of the block

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate that it is a means for the developers of the wallet to draw a profit without having to actually sell the wallet software.